# Problem dealing with a second-order linear ODE.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve:
$$(x^2-1)y'' - 2xy' + 2y = x^2-1 \quad  \quad (1)$$
Knowing that one of the solutions for
$$(x^2-1)y'' -2xy' + 2y = 0 \quad \quad  (2)$$ is $y_1(x) = x$.
So first of all, applying D'Alembert's method:
$$y_2(x) = v(x) y_1(x)$$
$$y_2' = v' x + v$$
$$y_2'' = v''x + 2v$$
Plugging in $(2)$:
$$v''(x^3-x) + v'(-2) = 0$$
$$v''(x^3-x) = 2v'$$
And so, let $\mu(x) = v'(x)$, we get $\mu'= \frac{2}{x^3-x}\mu$ and hence $$\mu = e^{\int\frac{2}{x^3-x}dx}$$
Since $\int \frac{2}{x^3-x}dx = \ln(|\frac{1}{x^2} -1|)$, we get $$\mu = e^{\ln(|\frac{1}{x^2} -1|)}$$
Here is my first problem: For $|x| < 1$, i get $\mu = \frac{1-x^2}{x^2}$ and for $|x| > 1$ i get $\mu = \frac{-1+x^2}{x^2}$. Which one should i "choose"? I would work with them both (for me it seems like is the most correct thing to do), but apperently i shouldn't, because the answer to the problem doesn't specify the domain at all. The second problem appears when i try to apply the variaton of parameters method to solve the equation. This looks silly. Any ideas?

---

**Assuming $y_2(x) = 1+x^2$**:
The wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$ is $2x^2-(1+x^2) = x^2-1$.
Using Cramer's rule to solve the system of variation of parameters method:
$$v_2 = \int \frac{ y_1 f(x)}{W(y_1,y_2)}dx \quad (3)$$
Where $f(x) = x^2-1$ and $W(y_1,y_2)$ is the Wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$.
(Here, $v_2$ comes from the fact that we are assuming the existence of a particular solution to $(1)$ defined as $y_p = v_1 y_1 + v_2 y_2$ where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions to $(2)$ and $v_1$ and $v_2$ are non-constant functions).

So, computing integral $(3)$:
$$v_2 = \int \frac{x \cdot ( x^2-1)}{x^2-1}dx = \frac{x^2}{2}$$
And so one part of the particular solution would be $y = \frac{x^2}{2} (x^2+1)$ which i don't think it's right.

---

Question 'official' answer:
$$y(x) = -x^2 + x \ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x}) + \frac{1}{2}(1+x^2)\ln(1-x^2) + C_1x + C_2 (x^2+1)$$

Comment: You move from $v'=μ=\frac{1+x}{x^2}$ to $y_2=xv=1+x^2$. How did you get that, as 
$$
v=-\frac1x+\ln|x|
$$
leads to $y_2=-1+x\ln|x|$?

Comment: Answer: It should be $v'=μ=\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}$. As the assembled second solution $y_2=1+x^2$ is free of singularities at $x=\pm1$, it is valid globally. Remember that the full homogeneous solution has a factor in front of $y_2$ which includes sign variations.

Comment: Yes! I mistyped the value of $v'$.. I will correct.

Comment: @LutzL, about the fact the factor that includes sign variations in front of $y_2$. What sign should i put in the wronksian? The positive, right?

Comment: Your resolution of the absolute value is still not correct, a difference can not become a sum of positive terms. -- Once you fix $v_2$ as a globally continuous function, the sign problems during previous steps are hidden, do not play a further role.

Comment: I edited the question. Could you verify now?

Comment: Yes, that is now right-ish, there is an extra sign for the resolution of $|\mu|$. Still, with the integration constant you get $\mu =C(1-\frac1{x^2})$ in both cases, which gives the obvious continuous continuations over the definition gaps at $x=\pm1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you missed to take the leading coefficient into account. The variation of constants approach should lead to
\begin{align}
v_1'y_1+v_2'y_2&=0\\
(x^2-1)(v_1'y_1'+v_2'y_2')&=(x^2-1)\\
\implies
v_1'y_1'+v_2'y_2'&=1
\end{align}
so that
$$
v_1'=\frac{-y_2}{y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2},
\quad
v_2'=\frac{y_1}{y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2}
$$